# Converting data into fixed point binary in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, fixed-point

I am not a regular Matlab user, so I apologize if this question is naïve. I am working on a hardware project and would like to convert some data to fixed point binary using the fixed point toolbox.

All my data are float in nature and in the range of -1 to +1. I was trying to convert them into fixed point in Matlab, to no avail.

I have been getting different types of errors, from "Cell contents assignment to non cell array objects" to just wrong binary values. Below is my code.

```
for i=1:count
    temp=datax(i); % datax is a array of decimal values between -1 and 1

    fixeda{i}=bin(sfi(temp,16,15)); 
    % Since all values are in the same range I set the word length to be 16 and fractional part to be 15
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a matlab user, but shouldn't the 1.15 representation of a float between -1 and 1 just be `int(f*32768)`

Note that you can only represent numbers less than 1.0 in this representation. 1.0 exactly causes an overflow.

Looking at the help pages it looks like `fixeda = bin(sfi(datax,16,15))` should be all you need.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand. Could you explain a bit further.

Comment: Yes! But since it is an array and I want to save all the binary representations into another array, I am getting "Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object" error.

Comment: It doesn't go past the first value.

Comment: According to the examples, both `sfi` and `bin` will take array arguments and return arrays of the same size. Did you declare fixeda as something before attempting to write to it?